# Pegar retorno JSON sem "result" em Ajax ou retornar sem "result" em Delphi

Tags: ajax, json, google-charts, delphi-xe5, mormot

Eu estou gerando um `JSON` em `Delphi` com [`mORMot`](https://synopse.info/fossil/wiki?name=SQLite3+Framework) e preciso pegar ele em uma página pra gerar uns gráficos com [`Google Chart`](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/), porém o `Delphi` me retorna o `JSON` dentro de um `result`. Eu só monto a string numa função com retorno do tipo `RawJSON`. Ele vem dessa forma:

```
{
  "result":[
    {
      "cols":[
        {"id":"","label":"Mês","pattern":"","type":"string"},
        {"id":"","label":"Quantidade","pattern":"","type":"number"}
      ],
      "rows":[
        {"c":[{"v":"Agosto de 2016","f":null},{"v":191,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Setembro de 2016","f":null},{"v":188,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Outubro de 2016","f":null},{"v":230,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Novembro de 2016","f":null},{"v":243,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Dezembro de 2016","f":null},{"v":145,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Janeiro de 2017","f":null},{"v":245,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Fevereiro de 2017","f":null},{"v":206,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Março de 2017","f":null},{"v":174,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Abril de 2017","f":null},{"v":241,"f":null}]}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Porém eu preciso dele assim que é o que eu estou gerando:

```
{
  "cols":[
    {"id":"","label":"Mês","pattern":"","type":"string"},
    {"id":"","label":"Quantidade","pattern":"","type":"number"}
  ],
  "rows":[
    {"c":[{"v":"Agosto de 2016","f":null},{"v":191,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Setembro de 2016","f":null},{"v":188,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Outubro de 2016","f":null},{"v":230,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Novembro de 2016","f":null},{"v":243,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Dezembro de 2016","f":null},{"v":145,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Janeiro de 2017","f":null},{"v":245,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Fevereiro de 2017","f":null},{"v":206,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Março de 2017","f":null},{"v":174,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Abril de 2017","f":null},{"v":241,"f":null}]}
  ]
}
```

Na página eu pego o JSON dessa forma:

```
var jsonData = $.ajax({
      url:      'http://localhost/api/graficos',
      dataType: "json",
      async:    false
    }).responseText;
```

Comment: Console.log(jsonData) imprimi o que? Já tentou colocar jsonData.result? Veja o [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7d50wowe/) que fiz aqui.

Comment: Não funcionou, dá uma olhada lá no [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7d50wowe/4/), eu coloquei o código. Se remover "result" do JSON ele funciona.

Comment: No Delphi, declare Data.DBXPlatform no uses, na sua função a onde você gera o JSON coloque o seguinte código GetInvocationMetadata().ResponseCode := 200;
GetInvocationMetadata().ResponseContent := Result.ToString;

Answer (score -1):

Consegui resolver utilizando o `JSON.parse` no resultado da requisição, pois ele traz uma `string` e o `Google Charts` espera um objeto:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonData);
```

Depois pra pegar o `JSON` sem o `result` chamei assim `jsonData.result[0]`, isso mostra o que está dentro do `result`.